# Factor out a constant from a matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

I've got a matrix in which every entry is of the form x/4. I cant find out how to factor out the 1/4 so that the actual matrix is clearer.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I suspect you are so going to kick yourself in about 10 seconds.  matrix*4, NOT matrix.4

Comment: Yes. But what I meant was if mathematica can automatically factor that out so that the 1/4 is in front of the matrix?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. What you meant is you want  Mathematica to use your idea of what is "simpler." That is a much harder problem to solve well. You can sometimes use things like Hold[] or Unevaluated[] to stop it from doing what it wants, look at the documentation for those to see if that helps. But often it seems that the more you want to disagree with the way Mathematica wants to do something the more difficult it becomes. I hope it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks. It is not exactly how I would want it, but I got the idea what to do!

Comment: Have a look at `Defer` and `Interpretation`, e.g., `Defer[Evaluate[mat*4 // MatrixForm]]*1/4` where *mat* is your matrix. You can use these to provide a visually appealing representation that is still usable in calculations...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the question has been solved with a comment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issued raised is not really a problem, but a misunderstanding of how _Mathematica_ works.